# I want to make a tachometer that uses CDI (capacitor discharge ignition) signals to measure RPM. How can I measure the high voltage with an Arduino?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, digital-logic, high-voltage, voltage-measurement

I have a Chinese unbranded ~ 50cc chainsaw engine. I tried numerous times to use it to power a bike but in vain. I found online that the RPM is very high -  around 10k RPM. I decided to do it right by measuring the RPM. I needed to measure it from the CDI because later I would also want to measure torque and it would be much easier this way. A tachometer costs a lot where I live and I can't afford it, but I have a lot of electronics and I can borrow some parts from my university if I need. I also wanted to build a circuit to replace the CDI with a Hall effect sensor.  This project would be a good introduction to this subject.

My questions are:

1. I don't know the voltage that the CDI outputs, if I did I could have built a voltage divider and measured the signal with an Arduino. I wanted to take a hint and measure the gap that the spark flies across but I don't think it would be close enough.How should I measure the high voltage if it is the right approach?
2. If it was in the 10k RPM range would the Arduino even be able to calculate it right?
3. For the code, I think I should make a variable and add to it each time I get a high and then after 60 seconds print it out to serial and set the variable to 0 again, will this work?

Edit 1 : an idea just came to my mind, could I use something like 5v zener or 7-8 schottky diodes wired with the voltage and measure the voltage across them for my 5v logic, if doesn't work please tell me how because I don't know if it would work or not ?

Comment: A common method is to tie a sense wire in parallel with the ignition wire. The sense wire is coupled through a capacitor and resistor and is clamped by diodes. Then into the input capture pin. Measure he period, but you need to blank the input after a pulse as the ignition coil rings and gives multiple pulses for a 100 or so microseconds.

Comment: 10,000 RPM is very slow in electronics terms (167Hz), but it would be better to use the capture/compare peripherals on the Arduino chip. Maybe you can count for less time and get a faster update rate. Maybe you use the hall sensor for measuring the RPM, would be less risk of getting a spark which would destroy something or other.

Comment: Kartman by sense wire do you mean em field of the wire, also doesn't the capacitor take time to charge and discharge wouldn't this decrease accuracy, spehro adding a hall effect sensor is a big work because of how the engine is designed and the fly wheel have a big magnet third the circumference.

Comment: http://allegrobotics.com/rpm.html   Not that i endorse this site, but it illustrates the general idea. Accuracy shouldn’t be an issue. The technique has been around for decades and is used in many commercial products. Using input capture you can measure the speed on each rotation - in fact you need to filter the reading as it jumps around alot due to the engine. Years ago i built a little bluetooth rpm transmitter for my racing gokart. I used my smartphone to log the data.

Comment: I visited the site he doesn't seem to explain anything, but using a coil is a safe bet although the writer stated that the arduino crashed a number of times.

Comment: But I wanted to calculate the high voltage, Because as I stated I wanted to replace the cdi and make an electronic one so I need the voltage anyway.

Comment: @AhmedH2O Ah, maybe I misunderstood that you intend to add the Hall sensor anyway.

Comment: @Spehro yes I intend to add it but after I know the rpm and torque to decide if this project is even worth it because I don't have any place to add the sensor yet and it introduces more errors that I don't want to get myself in now, and if I added the sensor I can't resell it anymore if it doesn't fit my use.

Comment: You'd be better using an IR optical solution for RPM measurement, it avoids all the noise from the spark system. Having built lots of CDI in the past I'm not sure why you are interested in the absolute pulse voltage from your CDI, it does not tell you much.

Comment: I think it is the simplest way and the engine has crazy vibration, also I measure it outdoors in the sun because I can't run it in an apartment and as I said I wanted to at least measure the voltage to make an electronic ignition in the future.

Comment: I didn't really consider the noise, is it really that significant? Could I use something with schmitt?

Comment: I made an edit to use 7-8 schottky diodes and measure the voltage across them, I could also filter the noise before connecting it to the diodes, also I think I need to add a resistor so it doesn't draw a lot of current and stall the engine because the connection I make is a bridge between the 2 wires that are meant to stop the engine.

Comment: I wonder if there's an optical way of doing this, with a phone app. See https://apps.apple.com/us/app/strobe-tachometer-rpm-meter/id831460940 I wonder if there's a part there that has an optical change once per rotation. Also, 10k RPM is pushing it. Maybe you can still work with a half harmonic.

Comment: I'm not against the optical solution as Jack also mentioned a use of a cheap ir receiver & transmitter but I would like to build it with signal because I have future projects that this build would help me understand more of what I should do, also my phone is a cheap old phone with no ir transmitter.